# How to use INDIRECT to use a string in a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table which I put all the data, grouped by each column. In another sheet, I'm trying to do an average with some filtering:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(Table2[seqLength],Table2[successRate],(Table2[successRate]>0)+0)/SUMIF(Table2[successRate], ">0", Table2[seqLength]), $D$4)
```

This gives me an weighted average success rate, excluding any cases where everything failed.

Now, I'm trying to substitute the name of the parameter `seqLength` by referencing a cell that contains the name of the parameter. Let's say that the value of the cell B1 is `seqLength`.

I've tried couple of configurations, but excel keeps complaining that they are invalid syntax. Please help :(

Comment: replace all your `Table2[seqLength]` with `INDIRECT("Table2[" & B1 & "]")`

Comment: @Scott you should add that as an answer.